# Fibonacci series using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to generate a **Fibonacci series** of first ten element using recursion. But the compiler give error. Please help me to find the exact solution.

// The program is given below:

```
public class DemoJava {

    int a=0, b=1, c=0, count=10;

    public void fibonacciRecursion(count) {

        if(count>0){

            c = a+b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            System.out.println(c);
            fibonacciRecursion(count-1);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("This is a Demo Program.");
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);

        DemoJava dj = new DemoJava();
        dj.fibonacciRecursion((count-2));
    }
}
```

// Error is given below:

```
error: <identifier> expected
        public void fibonacciRecursion(count) {
                                            ^
1 error
```

Comment: voted to close as too broad, please read a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) to get an idea of basics of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void fibonacciRecursion(int count)
```

You missed the `int` in the method signature.

Secondly,

```
dj.fibonacciRecursion((count-2));
```

This should be written as:

```
dj.fibonacciRecursion((dj.count-2));
```

because `count` is an instance variable.

Comment: I tried it but the compiler again give errors      error: non-static variable count cannot be referenced from a static context
                dj.fibonacciRecursion((count-2));

Comment: @NathanHughes, thanks for pointing out. I meant signature.

Comment: @MohdAqib, please check edited answer.

Comment: @MohdAqib You cannot access the `count` variable inside your main method unless it was declared inside the main method itself. Otherwise, the best you can do is make `count` static.

Comment: @blahfunk, actually he can, by accessing it through the object he created.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. Now it is work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well...

I'm pretty sure you have to specify the variable type on a method parameter, something like this:

```
public void fibonacciRecursion(int count) {
```